# IIS - How to downgrade self signed SSL certificate to 1024 bits?

Tags: asp.net, iis, ssl, windows-server-2012, iis-8

Firstly, thank you for the taking the time out to read this post.

I'm running a demo development web server which is hosting my ASP.net Web API in IIS8.
My API is setup to work only via SSL, but I need the self signed SSL key to be 1024 bits rather than 2048 due to the limitations of my Microchip PIC Microcontroller that connects to it.

Can anyone advise me on how I can generate a self signed SSL certificate to be 1024 bits rather than the default 2048?

Please note that I am new to network/web programming so I'm trying to work things out as I go along. Thus far this is my first demo web applications.

Many thanks,

Rob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I managed to create a key size of 1024 using microsofts selfssl tool which is part of their IIS6 Resource Toolkit.

This has solved my problem.